# A question about rings of algebraic integers

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $R$ be a subring of the field of algebraic numbers. If $R\cap \mathbb{Q}= \mathbb{Z}$, does it follow that all of the elements of $R$ are algebraic integers?

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not true in general. For example, let $R=\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ with an algebraic number $\alpha$ which is not an algebraic integer, and such that $R\cap \mathbb{Q}=\mathbb{Z}$, e.g., 
$$
\alpha=\frac{3-\sqrt{2}}{7}.
$$
Then indeed $R\cap \mathbb{Q}=\mathbb{Z}$, but not all elements are algebraic integers.
In fact, the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ is given by $f(x)=x^2 - \frac{6}{7}x + \frac{1}{7}$, which does not have integer coefficients.

Comment: May I ask why you chose this particular example?

Comment: Okay, I see. But why does this work and, say $\alpha = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$, doesn't? I'm just curious.

Comment: Because then $\alpha^2 = \frac{1}{2} \notin \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Dietrich, Would you be so kind as to explain why R∩ℚ=ℤ in the case of yor example? This doesn't seem obvious to me.

Comment: For a proof (in a similar case) see for example [here](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=1675915) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sci.math.research/EGxV2pCQNp4). I am still looking for a reference on MSE.

Comment: I think that a proof can be based on the idea of using the valuation related to the prime $\mathfrak{p}=(3+\sqrt2)$ of $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt2]$ also lying above $7$. The number $\alpha$ is not a $\mathfrak{p}$-adic integer, so no non-constant polynomial with integer coefficients evaluated at $\alpha$ can be one either. OTOH the elements of this ring all are integers w.r.t. the valuation related to the prime $\mathfrak{p}'=(3-\sqrt2)$. Putting this together with the fact that for rational numbers there is no difference between $\mathfrak{p}$ and $\mathfrak{p}'$-adic values seems to give the claim.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\alpha=(3-\sqrt{2})/7$.
Here is a proof-sketch of the statement $$\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]\cap \mathbb{Q}= \mathbb{Z},$$ based on the facts that the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ is a unique factorization domain, and $3-\sqrt{2}$ is a prime element of this ring.

Let $L$ be a $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combination of powers of $\alpha$. Plainly $L$ has the form $\beta/7^k$ with $\beta\in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ and $k\ge0$. Suppose  that $\beta\in \mathbb{Z}$. We can assume that the fraction $\beta/7^k$ is in lowest terms. Then $k$ must be 0: Otherwise the prime $3-\sqrt{2}$
appears to a negative power in $\beta/7^k$.  But $3-\sqrt{2}$ appears to the power 0 in $\alpha$, hence to a non-negative power in $L$.